# Unable to import packages while intializing java classes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, eclipse

I have downloaded and imported Selenium 3.60 jars but unable to import packages:

```
package basics;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Synchronization {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","N://drivers//geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS); //implicit wait
        driver.get("https://alaskatrips.poweredbygps.com/g/pt/hotels?MDPCID=ALASKA-US.TPS.BRAND.hotels.HOTEL");
        driver.findElement(By.id("H-destination")).sendKeys("nyc");
        driver.findElement(By.id("H-destination")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB); //tab operation
        driver.findElement(By.id("H-fromDate")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 

        WebDriverwait d=new Webriverwait(5,driver);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@href,'North-Bergen-Hotels-Howard-Johnson')]")).click();



    }

}
```

Comment: What is your problem? This is just the code. What are the symptoms?

Comment: The thing is when i initialize the WebDriver wait class,i am not able to import anything related to it,hence could not execute it.So,is there any external jars to import.I have imported all jars under Selenium 3.6.0

Comment: Do you have selenium jars attached to your eclipse project or pom.xml dependencies configured (in case if you use maven) ?

Comment: I attached selenium jars to eclipse and i dont have pom.xml as i am not using maven. I have downloaded Java 3.6.0  jars from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: In the downloaded selenium jars,there are very limited jars around 10.I am wondering whether 3.6.0 version minimized the jars or i have done wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some problems right here are following:

1. You are trying to use constructor of the class **WebDriverWait** to behave as a method of waiting for 5 seconds for some action. This won't work.
2. There is no constructor for the class **WebDriverWait** that takes first argument as integer (in your code you're passing 5)
   From the official http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html

[image]

Try to implicitly import (I mean type in your class) package **org.openqa.selenium.support.ui** and see it this would help.